# How can I use shortcut to open the IntelliSense on Visual studio for mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

[This is the issue image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2BCa.png)

Like I say, how can I to open this one on visual studio for Mac version ?

On windows visual studio, I can use the shortcut keys (ctrl + j), but on the Mac, this doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio for Mac the default shortcut to open the intellisense window is Ctrl+Space.

You can change the default shortcuts in Preferences - Environment - Key Bindings. The shortcut is called Complete Word and is available in the Text Editor group.

[image: Key bindings]

You can either change the shortcut individually, or you can select `Visual Studio (Windows)` as the Scheme which will change the shortcuts to match those on Windows.